# web2py add row in form table

Tags: row, web2py

I'm building an edifact translator/editor.  For displaying an existing translation I have the following controller:

```
import shutil
import sys
import fileinput

def edit_datafile():
    #inlees gedeelte van een bestaand datatype
    file = open('/home/wouter/DESADVCB.pcf', 'r')
    datas = []
    data = {}
    row = {}
    j = 1
    for line in file:
        meg = line.strip().split(':', 3)
        if line.startswith('#'):
            c = 1
            unmark = line.strip().split('#')
            datas.append('#')
            datas.append(unmark[1])
            data[j,c] = datas
            datas=[]
            j = j+1
        else:
        if '.' in meg[0]:
                t = meg[0].split('.')
                if '+' in t[0]:
                    a = t[0].split('+')
                    datas.append(a[0])
                    datas.append(a[1])
                else:
                   datas.append(t[0])
                   datas.append(t[1])
               try:
                    t[2]
                    datas.append(t[2])
               except IndexError, e:
                    datas.append('')

        else:
            if '+' in meg[0]:
                a = meg[0].split('+')
                datas.append(a[0])
                datas.append(a[1])
            else:
                datas.append(meg[0])
                datas.append('')
            datas.append('')
            datas.append('')               
        datas.append(meg[1])
        datas.append(meg[2])
        try:
            meg[3]
            if ':' in line:
                reg = meg[3].strip().split(':')
                c = 1
                for teg in reg:
                    seg = teg.split('=')
                    if '.' in seg[0]:
                        t = seg[0].split('.')
                        datas.append(t[0])
                        datas.append(t[1])
                        try:
                            t[2]
                            datas.append(t[2])
                        except IndexError, a:
                            datas.append('')
                        try:
                            t[3]
                            datas.append(t[3])
                        except IndexError, a:
                            datas.append('')
                            s= seg[1].split('.', 3)
                            datas.append(s[0])
                            datas.append(s[1])
                            datas.append(s[2])
                            datas.append(s[3])
                            data[j,c]=datas
                        c = c+1
                    else:
                        datas.append(seg[0])
                        datas.append('')
                        datas.append('')
                        datas.append('')
                        s= seg[1].split('.', 3)
                        datas.append(s[0])
                        datas.append(s[1])
                        datas.append(s[2])
                        datas.append(s[3])
                        data[j,c]=datas
                        c= c+1
                    datas=[]
                j = j+1   
            else:
                seg = meg[3].strip().split('=')
                if '.' in seg[0]:
                    t = seg[0].split('.')
                    datas.append(t[0])
                    datas.append(t[1])
                    try:
                        t[2]
                        datas.append(t[2])
                    except IndexError, a:
                        datas.append('')
                    try:
                        t[3]
                        datas.append(t[3])
                    except IndexError, a:
                        datas.append('')

                else:
                    datas.append(seg[0])
                    datas.append('')
                    datas.append('')
                    datas.append('')
                s= seg[1].split('.', 3)
                datas.append(s[0])
                datas.append(s[1])
                datas.append(s[2])
                datas.append(s[3])
                data[j] = datas
                datas=[]
                j = j+1  
        except IndexError, a:
            c = 1
            datas.append('')
            datas.append('')
            datas.append('')
            datas.append('')
            datas.append('')
            datas.append('')
            datas.append('')
            datas.append('')
            data[j,c] = datas
            datas=[]
            j = j+1 
# form om regels toe te voegen
form_ar = FORM(
            TABLE(THEAD(
                TR(
                    TH('Nieuw:'),
                    TH('Toevoegen:'),
                    TH('Nummer:')
                    )),
                TBODY(TR(
                    TD(SELECT('rij','remark', value='rij',_name='t')),
                    TD(SELECT('voor', 'na', value='na',_name='w')),
                    TD(SELECT([(key,'.',skey) for (key,skey) in sorted(data.iterkeys())],_name='p')),
                    TD(INPUT(_type="submit", _name="make", _value="Maak"))
            ))))

form_er = FORM(
            TABLE(
                THEAD(TR(
                    TH('Line'),
                    TH('Name'),
                    TH('Qualifier'),
                    TH('Field'),
                    TH('Subfield'),
                    TH('Match'),
                    TH('Set'),
                    TH('Field'),
                    TH('Subfield'),
                    TH('Position'),
                    TH('Length'),
                    TH('Position'),
                    TH('Lenght'),
                    TH('Type'),
                    TH('Name')
                )),
                TBODY([TR(
                    TD(key,'.',skey),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='N',_value=data[key,skey][0],_style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='Q',_value=data[key,skey][1]), _colspan=13,_style='width:450px'), rowid=data[key,skey]
                 )
                 if data[key,skey][0]=='#' else 
                 TR(
                    TD(key,'.',skey),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='N',_value=data[key,skey][0], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='Q',_value=data[key,skey][1], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='IF',_value=data[key,skey][2], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='IS',_value=data[key,skey][3], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='IM',_value=data[key,skey][4], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='IT',_value=data[key,skey][5], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OF',_value=data[key,skey][6], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OS',_value=data[key,skey][7], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='IP',_value=data[key,skey][8], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='IL',_value=data[key,skey][9], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OP',_value=data[key,skey][10], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OL',_value=data[key,skey][11], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OT',_value=data[key,skey][12], _style='width:10px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='ON',_value=data[key,skey][13])), rowid=data[key,skey]
                ) 
                if skey==1 else 
                TR(
                    TD(key,'.',skey),
                    TD(_maxlength='3',_size='3'),
                    TD(_colspan=5),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OF',_value=data[key,skey][0], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OS',_value=data[key,skey][1], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='IP',_value=data[key,skey][2], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='IL',_value=data[key,skey][3], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OP',_value=data[key,skey][4], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OL',_value=data[key,skey][5], _style='width:30px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='OT',_value=data[key,skey][6], _style='width:10px')),
                    TD(INPUT(_name='ON',_value=data[key,skey][7])), rowid=data[key,skey]
                ) for (key,skey) in sorted(data.iterkeys())]),_id="example",_class="display"),
            INPUT(_type="submit", _name="save", _value="Save Page")
           )
return dict(data=data,form_ar=form_ar, form_er=form_er, f=f)
```

the file is like this:

```
BGM+351::1:2=1.8.0.doorlopend nummer CobanaFruchtring
#remark test
DTM+191:::1.3=316.8.D.aankomstdatum (verwacht)
NAD+SU:::2=46.8.0.Lieferantennummer:4.1=54.9..Lieferantenname 
NAD+BY:::2=63.8.0.ontvangernummer:4.1=71.9..ontvangernaam
TDT+20:::8.4=299.17..bootnaam
CPS::2
LIN::3
PIA+5:::3.1=80.34..Hoofdsoort/Varieteit:4.1=216.17..EAN-code:5.1=182.17..Verpakking
PIA+1:::2.1=114.17..Marke:3.1=29.17..Ursprungland  ISO-code:4.1=250.8..Size:5.1=148.17..Qualitaetsbezeichnung
MEA+AAA.2.1:::3.2=423.8.3.nettogewicht per collo
MEA+AAB.2.1:::3.2=439.8.3.brutogewicht per collo
MEA+AAJ.2.1:::3.2=258.4.0.vpp
QTY+21:::1.2=455.8.0.verwachte colli
FTX+PAL:::4.1=182.17..Palettenart
RFF+ON:::1.2.1.7=233.6.0.Partie-Nummer:1.2.8.3=239.3..Partie-pos
RRF+ZZZ:::1.2.1.8=471.8.2.SBX partijnummer:1.2.16.4=479.4..SBX varieteitscode:1.2.20.4=483.4..SBX merkcode:1.2.28.4=487.4..SBX categoriecode:1.2.32.4=490.1..SBX verpakkingscode
LOC+18:::2.4=324.17..Ankunfthafen
PCI+IEN:::2=262.11..Containernummer
```

I want to be able to add rows in the form without a submit on a desired position. I have looked at powertable, datatables and jQuery to accomplish this but I cannot seem to find a suitable solution.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to add row dynamicly to the table in any position.

If so, you can use jQuery method before() or after().

For example, to insert row before selected row:

```
$('#table tbody tr').live('click',function(event) {
    $(this).before("<tr><td>data1</td></tr>")
});
```